# Eclipse console output formatting issue

Tags: java, eclipse, console, formatting

I have set the console to have a fixed width and I have also increased the text size of the console output. I have a custom method which takes each character of a string and displays it in `System.out`, one character at a time with a `Thread.sleep` in between each character output.
It was working fine until I changed the size of the text, but changing it back does not work. Basically once it hits the max width, it doesn't continue printing the characters, some of them do print out but most of them do not. However if I change the font size after it has run, all the text appears the way it should, but I can never get it to appear this way on the first run of the application. I hope I am explaining this well enough. Please let me know if you would like any more information. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
  I am not sure how to edit my comment to post the code correctly so i'll add it in here
here is the code for the method:

```
public static void delayedPrint(int delay, String s){
        try {
            for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
                System.out.print(c);
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I implement it here:

```
    delayedPrint(40,"You wake. You remember nothing. Nothing is familiar: not the smell, which hangs in the air like the inside of a Lysol bottle, nor the taste—yes the room has a taste…like a college dining hall cleaned with dirty rags. And not the sight: This is a hospital cot, isn’t it?");
```

This works fine until I turn on fixed width in the console settings, that's when the output becomes wonky when it reaches the max width.

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: I have added what I believe to be the relevant code into my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how much of an answer this is

Something similar is happening when i try it as well. I am quite sure its an Eclipse thing though, because if you run it on cmd, it works just fine. I found a way around it that prints all characters fine for me.

So, assuming you have a fixed width of 80 characters lets say. Then you can do the following:

```
public static void delayedPrint(int delay, String s){
        int charCounter = 0;
        try {
            for (char c : s.toCharArray()){     
                System.out.print(c);
                charCounter++;
                if(charCounter % 80 == 0) System.out.println();//Replace 80 with your console width
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

So basically force a linebreak every time you reach the console width. I am not sure how useful it is for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for, but it is a valid solution that i will use. thanks!